# How to edit iPhone photos from Mac

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

I want to develop a simple photo editor.

Basically application should just crop photos on iPhone.

I was looking for solution on iPhone, but found that Apple does not allow third party developers to edit photos in Photo Library.

Is there a possibility to do this from Mac?

Or I missed something and it can be managed from iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pull the photos from the Library and edit/save them freely if the user grants you the permissions to access the photos. You can only replace existing photos if your app created them in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for response. But I want to edit photos created by user from iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an app which functions as below:

1. Access Photos Library using `UIImagePickerController` and get Image in your app. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html)
2. Crop your image. Check [this](http://www.samwirch.com/blog/cropping-and-resizing-images-camera-ios-and-objective-c)
3. Save the cropped image to PhotoLibrary using following code:

   `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, nil, nil, NULL);`

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: But in this case user will have two versions of photo.

Comment: yes thats true.. This is the only way to do it. Even if you check Default Photo app, its doing the same, When you try to edit a synced photo it create another copy in camera roll.

Comment: Yes. I know this. But I'm looking for solution that does not require additional user interactions. It may be implemented either on iPhone or on mac.

Answer (score 0):

As Kapil said you can use imagepicker to access the photos from library. If you need to develop a photo editor application you can have a look at this sample [here](http://code4app.net/ios/CLImageEditor/529372bccb7e84584c8b5b26).
From iOS8 or later its also good looking at the photo editing extension [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SamplePhotoEditingExtension/Introduction/Intro.html).